# Posso utilizar código jQuery em um .Factory e fazer o inject no controller?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, angular

Estou desenvolvendo um site utilizando AngularJS ES6, e nesse site eu precisava executar uma função e não estava conseguindo. Pesquisei na internet uma função semelhante para entender como eu poderia fazer e achei uma função em jQuery.

Na tentativa de passar esse código no controller da minha página apareceu alguns erros de sintaxe e descobri que não posso usar jQuery com ES6 (me corrijam se eu estiver errado). E ai o que eu fiz? fui na tela de services, onde eu chamo serviços WCF (.factory), joguei o código lá, fiz o inject no controller e deu certo.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte, apesar de ter funcionado, isso é correto? Eu posso fazer isso quando quero usar jQuery ou tenho que transformar esse código jQuery para JavaScript e usar apenas o controller?

Comment: Olá, td bem?
Explique melhor por favor?
Qual o código que vc quer usar do Jquery?
Não é muito bacana misturar os 2. Angular e Jquery.

Vc está usando o angular 2 (4 ou 5) ou o Angular 1 (AngularJs)?

Comment: jQuery nada tem a ver com ES6.

Comment: É um código que puxa os dados de uma planilha do excel e cria uma tabela no template, só consegui achar em jQuery :/